# Notepad ++ Reg Exp - Move end of line to beginning of line

Tags: regex, notepad++

I am trying to swap the content beginning from the hyphen in each line to the start of each line. I can find the hyphen with (-.*) But I don't know the regexp for the "Replace with:"

**Example of how the code looks right now:**

```
Beet - ½ cup
Strawberry - ½ cup
Mango - ½ cup
```

**Desired Outcome:**

```
- ½ cup Beet 
- ½ cup Strawberry
- ½ cup Mango
```

I appreciate your help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find what:

```
^(\S+)\s+(-.*)
```

OR

```
^([^-]*)\s+(-.*)
```

Replace With:

```
\2 \1
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/vW2pQ7/22)

Comment: Works like a charm. Appreciate the fast help Avinash!